# How to upload and show avatars in php?

Tags: php, upload, avatar

Ok i want to load a Avatar with my users regso they can upload and make a profile page i have user reg and everything and im using a flat file in php?

Answer (score 7):

You should consider integrating an existing avatar service such as [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) into your application. It might end up saving you and your users a bundle of time. From the Gravatar website:

> A gravatar, or globally recognized avatar, is quite simply an image that follows you from site to site appearing beside your name when you do things. Avatars help identify your posts on blogs and web forums, so why not on any site?

Answer (score 1):

Just treat the avatar upload like any photo upload. Create an avatar/image upload form to upload the image to your server in the profile page.